# Unable to POST my data using retrofit android using kotlin

Tags: android, post, kotlin, http-status-code-404, retrofit2

I am new to android studio and kotlin. I have trying to post my data(object) onto the server but I'm getting a 404 response code.

My retrofit:

```
object RetrofitClient {
private var OurInstance : Retrofit?=null
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
val instance:Retrofit
get() {
    if (OurInstance==null)
    {
        OurInstance =Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://coreapi.imagin8ors.org:8080/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()
    }
    return OurInstance!!
  }
}
```

My interface:

```
interface IMyAPI {
@GET("v1/child/{dynamic}/learningpods_new")
fun getDynamic(@Path("dynamic")dynamic:String):Observable<ArrayList<Data>>

@POST("v1/authenticate/create")
fun createParent(@Body parentDetails: ParentDetails):Call<ParentDetails>
}
```

Code snippet in my activity:

```
fun sendNetworkRequest(parentDetails: ParentDetails){
    val retrofit=Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://coreapi.imagin8ors.org:8080/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    val client=retrofit.create(IMyAPI::class.java)
    val call = client.createParent(parentDetails)
    call.enqueue(object :Callback<ParentDetails>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ParentDetails>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ParentmainActivity,"something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ParentDetails>?, response: Response<ParentDetails>?) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ParentmainActivity,"successful :"+response?.code(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    })
}
```

Function call: `sendNetworkRequest(new_parent)`

Now, the response code returned is 404. This issue has been raised previously but those solutions didn't work for me. That's why I have posted as another question.

The links I have referred to: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482738/unable-to-send-raw-json-data-in-post-api-data-using-retrofit-2-0), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267975/how-to-post-json-object-using-retrofit), [link3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7lRiTJ_-cI) and many more..

Initially I was using the retrofitclient but then it didn't work so I tried with the sendNetworkResquest() function. However, this too doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a `PUT` request. 
When I try your API with `POST` I actually get a `405 - Method Not Allowed`. But `PUT` works.. except that I am sending no data, so I get a `400`. But definitely not a `404`

```
curl -X POST http://.../create -> Method not allowed
curl -X PUT http://.../create -> Bad Request
```

Also double check that your body actually contains valid data in the required format, as specified by your backend endpoint, otherwise you'll get further errors

Comment: I have tried PUT request too. I still get a 404 response code. My target url on POSTMAN shows a 405 response code for POST request and 400 for PUT request.

Comment: I have modified the code and the question. Could you respond to the same?

Comment: Well it would have been nicer to accept the answer and post another question. Anyway, you still have a problem, probably with the format of what you are trying to upload. To help you I either need specifications, or a working curl or postman config. And maybe implementation for this createParent method

Comment: You were right? I needed a PUT request coz that was how how it was configured in the backend. However, the problem was with the parameters in the body that I was sending were wrong. Probably you could modify your answer to include this point as well(to accept it). Moreover, I have rollbacked the question, so that it perfectly matches you answer.

Comment: @Eswar I'd be glad to do so, but I have no idea about what's wrong with your body :)

Comment: Probably you could just say that PUT must be used and since it' an idempotent operation, the correct fields need to be passed. The correct fields can be passed only by the knowing how the back-end was configured for that particular end-point.